# Is this person Jessica Jones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones, iron-fist-2017

In "Blessing of Many Fractures," Joy mentions hiring a private investigator to follow her board members:

> JOY: I hired a private investigator a while ago to start digging. She was worth every penny…when
>   she was sober.

This certainly sounds similar to Jessica Jones (PI, female, drinks), but could also match a bunch of other PIs (not everything in the MCU needs to be an easter egg).

Is there any definite evidence (interviews, etc) that this is a reference to Jessica Jones?

Comment: Yes. It's obviously her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It was a subtle reference, but it was her. There is no point in mentioning gender and the alcohol issues unless it was an Easter Egg. Joy could have just said PI and been done with it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. OP was looking for "**definite evidence**"

Comment: At some point, you have to see 2+2 and realize it equals 4. There is no point in saying "She" was a good PI when she was sober and not be referring to Jessica Jones. That's like saying the "guy with unbreakable skin" isn't Luke Cage because they don't explicitly use his name. No one knows she has superpowers so that is the only way to refer to her.

Comment: The problem here is that you haven't answered the question that the OP asked. You've answered a different question "***Does Alemus think this person is Jessica Jones?***"

Comment: Then there is no answer that is going to satisfy OP.

Comment: I suspect that a comment in an interview would be more than sufficient.

Comment: Also, she hardly hides her powers. She lifted someone's car and told them she had laser eyes.  ;)

Comment: There will be references and parallels, because Jessica, Luke and Danny are going to be in the Defenders soon... and probably kept out of jail by Hogarth :)

Comment: ...and out of hospitals by Claire :)